Linguagem django allauth
Estou implementando o django allauth em meu código, tudo está funcionando corretamente, mas na página de login aparece um botão "Forgot your password?" ao invés de "Esqueceu sua senha?".
HTML:
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md padding-btn btn-success mt-3 mb-4 rounded-pill">Login</button>
            </form>

settings.py:
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'
USE_I18N = True

Alguém consegue me ajudar a transformar o texto em português?

você executou algum comando do manage.py? Aqueles compilemessages e o makemessages?

testei antes e depois de executar esses comandos e ainda sim não funcionou

ele gerou o diretório locale? Reiniciou a aplicação depois?

Para haver a tradução das mensagens, é necessário primeiro gerar as mensagens.
Para fazer isso basta executar o seguinte comando:
django-admin makemessages --locale=pt_BR

Observe que, para a execução correta certifique-se que parou o servidor de desenvolvimento, está executando com o ambiente virtual (virtualenv) ativo, caso utilize.
Caso tenha modificado alguma mensagem padrão, então será necessário primeiro gerar as mensagens e depois compilar, neste caso então, faça o seguinte:
django-admin makemessages --locale=pt_BR
django-admin compilemessages --locale=pt_BR

Para mais informações consulte a documentação makemessages e compilemessages

Funcionou, obrigado!
